# List applications preventing Windows 8 from shutting down

Tags: windows, windows-8, shutdown

Often, after I have initiated shutdown on Windows 8, I realize there are some applications I would like to close explicitly. I see that Windows 7 lists applications that are preventing the OS from shutting down and I have the option to abort the shutdown and take care of things.

How do I get Windows 8 to behave similar to Windows 7 when there are running applications preventing the OS from shutting down?

Comment: Windows 8 behaves like this by default.